# Does PEX leach BPA when used for hot water plumbing?

Tags: plumbing, pex

Would using PEX for potable hot water result in having [Bisphenol A (BPA)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisphenol_A) leached into the water?

Does PEX have BPA content?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be much unbiased information on this topic on the web. Comments on [this post on GreenBuildingAdvisor.com](http://www.greenbuildingadvisor.com/community/forum/green-products-and-materials/18789/pex-tubing) suggest that trace amounts of various chemicals, including BPA, may be found in PEX, but also point out that copper may not be ideal if you examine it closely.

Comment: I think somewhere some time ago, I saw a “spec sheet” from a PEX pipe maker saying you should not use PEX on a hot water “ring” that is pumped to always keep hot water next to each tap, this may be way.

Comment: It's been approved for use in California, which is saying a lot since most plastic products nowadays come with a tag "known to the State of California to cause cancer".

Comment: It appears as though with PEX, you should be concerned with [Methyl tert-butyl ether (MTBE)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methyl_tert-butyl_ether) and [Tert-Butanol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tert-Butanol). However, from what I could find both are only leached for a limited time. Most of the data I found was from before 2005, and some reports even mentioned that PEX manufacturers may have changed their manufacturing procedures to eliminate these two chemicals.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it's labeled for potable water, then it (technically) meets all regulations. Whether those regulations allow for a certain amount of BPA is what you'd want to check.

That said, one should not be ingesting hot water out of the tap. I'm less worried about the pipes and more worried about who-knows-what leaching/growing in the hot water tank. Hot water is for cleaning. Use cold water for all drinking and cooking.

Comment: Hot water tanks should always be set above 45 C (113 F), to prevent the growth of [Legionella pneumophila](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legionella_pneumophila) (Which can lead to [Legionellosis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legionnaires%27_disease)).

Comment: If you really want instant hot water for drinking/cooking, there are local water heaters which can be installed specifically for that purpose.

Comment: As an owner of an instant (tankless) heater, on copper piping, I feel perfectly safe drinking hot tap water.

Comment: @Bryce yes, a tankless system is much less worrisome.

Comment: Drinking from the tap is called ... Tapsy cola.